# oracle out in procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am trying to create the following procedure

```
create or replace procedure format_phone (ph in out varchar2) is 
begin
    ph:='('||substr(ph,1,3)||
        ')' || substr(ph,4,6)||
        '-'||substr(ph,7);
end;
/

declare 
    ph varchar2(11):='8006330575';
begin
    format_phone(ph);
end;
/
```

This exception is thrown:

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
declare 
    ph varchar2(11):='8006330575';
begin
    format_phone(ph);
end;

Error report:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: خطأ رقمي أو قيمة: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: عند "HR.FORMAT_PHONE", line 3
ORA-06512: عند line 4
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error"
```

Answer (score 1):

you just have to count, when ph is defined as varchar(11) it has allready a length of 10 chars.

in the function you add 3 more, so 10 + 3 = 13

13 > 11 => character string buffer too small

you have to define ph as minimum varchar(13) if the initial string has a length of 10

Comment: Close, the output for `8006330575` is `(800)633057-0575` which is 16 characters.